# How do I print elements of a list contained in a dictionary using a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary:

```
FFA = {'House': ['0.511', '0.374', 10], 'Chair': ['0.704', '0.381', 10], 'Shoe': ['0.922', '0.465', 10], 'Bottle': ['0.764', '0.348', 10], 'Face': ['1.084', '0.373', 10]}
```

I want to print certain elements in a for loop:

```
print "ROI", "Cope", "Mean", "Stddev", "Nsamples"
for k in FFA:
    print "FFA", k, elem[0], elem[1], elem[2]
```

That's my output:

```
 ROI Cope Mean Stddev Nsamples
FFA House 1.084 0.373 10
FFA Chair 1.084 0.373 10
FFA Shoe 1.084 0.373 10
FFA Bottle 1.084 0.373 10
FFA Face 1.084 0.373 10
```

However, my code is so wrong I can't find a way of iterating over all the keys in the dic so the right values are printed out.

I want my output to be:

```
ROI Cope Mean Stddev Nsamples
FFA House 0.511 0.374 10
FFA Chair 0.704 0.381 10
FFA Shoe  0.922 0.465 10
FFA Bottle 0.764 0.348 10
FFA Face 1.084 0.373 10
```

Comment: I'm really unclear on what your issue is or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: All the values of Face were printed out as for the other keys (House, Chair, Shoe and Bottle)

Comment: your code is unclear. you are referring to elements indexed from a list called `elem` yet you have no reference to this list in your question. what does `elem` contain and how is it populated.

Comment: **Do not** continue vandalising your own questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

```
print "ROI", "Cope", "Mean", "Stddev", "Nsamples"
for k in FFA:
    elem = FFA[k]
    print "FFA", k, elem[0], elem[1], elem[2]
```

or directly:

```
print "ROI", "Cope", "Mean", "Stddev", "Nsamples"
for k in FFA:
    print "FFA", k, FFA[k][0], FFA[k][1], FFA[k][2]
```

Comment: or just add `elem = FFA[k]`. Or use `.items()`, obviously, but I think it is instructive to show them this way

Answer (score 1):

Use `items()` to iterate over the keys and the values. Since you have multiple values, iterate over the values using the nested for loop over multiple values. For python 2.x it will be `print "FFA", k, values,`

```
print "ROI", "Cope", "Mean", "Stddev", "Nsamples" # Header

for k, v in FFA.items():
    # print ("FFA", k,  end=" ") # For python 3.x
    print "FFA", k,
    for values in v:
        print values,
        # print (values, end=" ") # For python 3.x
    print # To get to print to the new line
    # print ()  # For python 3.x
```

---

```
ROI Cope Mean Stddev Nsamples
FFA House 0.511 0.374 10 
FFA Chair 0.704 0.381 10 
FFA Shoe 0.922 0.465 10 
FFA Bottle 0.764 0.348 10 
FFA Face 1.084 0.373 10
```

Comment: remember to end the connecting lines after the for loop finished

Comment: @PatrickArtner: I wanted to ask OP if he/she has tagged python wrongly

Comment: @Bazingaa Judging from the print statement in the asker's code, I'd say python 2 is accurate.

Comment: The syntax of the `print` instruction shows that OP uses Python 2

Comment: @PatrickArtner: I guess `print "FFA", k, values,` should work on python 2

Comment: also, this is not the exact output the OP had

Comment: @glibdud: Sorry for all the confusion. I sorted it now

Comment: @GeorgeBou: Thanks for the pointer. Fixed it nowfor both python 2 and 3. let me know if there is still some glitch

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Sorry, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You already loop over the keys, now you simply need to loop over the elements of the values:

```
FFA = {'House': ['0.511', '0.374', 10], 
       'Chair': ['0.704', '0.381', 10], 
       'Shoe': ['0.922', '0.465', 10], 
       'Bottle': ['0.764', '0.348', 10], 
      'Face': ['1.084', '0.373', 10]} 

print "ROI", "Cope", "Mean", "Stddev", "Nsamples"


for k in FFA:      # loop over keys in dict 
    print "FFA", k,     # , at end == no newline
    for elem in FFA[k]: # loop over values in list of key
        print elem,         # , at end == no newline
    print               # now a newline
```

Output:

```
ROI Cope Mean Stddev Nsamples
FFA House 0.511 0.374 10
FFA Chair 0.704 0.381 10
FFA Shoe 0.922 0.465 10
FFA Bottle 0.764 0.348 10
```